# How to use scikit-learn metrics in CNTK?

Tags: python, neural-network, cntk

I wish to use classification metrics like `matthews_corrcoef` as a metric to a neural network built with CNTK. The way I could find as of now was to evaluate the value by passing the predictions and label as shown

`matthews_corrcoef(cntk.argmax(y_true, axis=-1).eval(), cntk.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1).eval())`

Ideally I'd like to pass the metric to the trainer object while building my network.
One of the ways would be to create own custom metric and pass that to the trainer object. Although possible, it'll be better to be able to reuse the already existing metrics present in other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this metric is already implemented in CNTK, implement your own custom "metric" function in whatever format CNTK requires, and have it pass the inputs on to scikit-learn's metric function.

Comment: To do that I'll have to wrap the scikit-learn metric as a CNTK variable/Function right? Can you tell me how to do that? Pardon my ignorance, new to this

Comment: Probably, I've never used CTNK before. Here's a [related question on CNTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/1148) that gives an example of how to do what you're asking.

Comment: Ill try to work and study more about this. Will update/add when and if I find something useful.